# How to read all database entries?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, delphi-xe8

This is the code I've got at the moment:

```
procedure TfrmLogin.performQuery;
begin
 query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM LoginDatabase';
 query.Open;
end;

procedure TfrmLogin.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 con := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
 query := TFDQuery.Create(con);
 con.LoginPrompt := false;
 con.Open('DriverID=SQLite;Database=C:\Users\katiee\Documents\Embarcadero\' +
 'Studio\Projects\ProgramDatabase;');
 query.Connection := con;
 performQuery;

 username := query.FieldByName('Username').AsString;
 passcode := query.FieldByName('Passcode').AsString;
end;

procedure TfrmLogin.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if (edtUsername.Text = username) and (edtPasscode.Text = passcode) then
 frmPayInfo.show
 else
 if MessageDlg('The username or password entered is incorrect.', mtWarning,
 [mbOK, mbCancel], 0) = mrCancel then
 frmLogin.Close;
end;
```

Right now the code, as it doesn't read all database entries, only allows the first database entry as correct answer.

I need to be able to enter any correct combination of username and pass-code from the database and open the form.

Comment: You seem to be trying to read all of the data from the table, and use program code to see if the username+passcode is in there. The better way to do it would be to provide the values to the query as parameters, and only fetch the data you need. Get the database to do the work. Don't send/receive data you don't need. Of course, the correct advice would be to say don't roll your own security. That is never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not call the .Locate method on the dataset? This way you will not be opening and closing the dataset, as you would need to with using a parameterised query.

Using the .Locate method will allow you to check (based off one, or many fields) if a certain record can be found.

If the record is found .Locate will return true.

For example.

```
if query.Locate('username;passcode', VarArrayOf([query.FieldByName('Username').AsString, query.FieldByName('Passcode').AsString]), [loPartialKey]) then
begin
 frmPayInfo.show;
end
else
begin
 Showmessage('User not found, or password incorrect');
end;
```

I haven't got Delphi on this machine, so syntax may not be 100%.